Arduino Nano ESD crash despite ESD protection measures
Good day!
I've just ran into a problem with a project of mine that I can't really figure out myself anymore. So i'm hoping someone on here will be able to help...
First things first, I'm trying to replace the controller of a split air conditioner after it's microcontroller went up in smoke. The idea is quite simple, three temperature sensors, three relays and a VFD for the indoor fan. Add to that three buttons and a small display.
The system is built as follows:

The issue I run into is that the addition of the 'circled' section consisting of a seperate UI panel with three buttons and a 128.64px OLED causes random hangs on the Arduino's code but ONLY if the High voltage section is powered.
If the display is not connected, the system runs fine, even when the compressor starts up and shuts down. The same is true with the display connected but the line voltage off (I.e. powered over USB)
The curious thing is that this only happens with the display section on it's 10cm long shielded and grounded ribbon cable, whereas two of the temperature sensors are ziptied to the main power wire for a length of almost five meters.
I have already gone and tried the usual methods for ESD protection. Adding clipping diodes into the UI box, capacitors over the switches to dampen any induced current spikes and adding a low-value resistor pair to the I²C bus (not on schematic yet). The entirety of the cable connecting the UI enclosure to the Arduino is shielded internally as well as a seperate wrap of heavy duty aluminum tape.
The High and low voltage sections of the circuit are completely seperated by relais, System ground, Shield ground, Chasis ground and mains ground are shorted together. The Arduino is only connected trough one of it's GND pins so no outside power can flow trough it's ground plane.
Still, as soon as the UI section is connected, the Arduino hangs until the watchdog resets it a while later only for it to happen again in a few minutes.
At this point I've tried everything short of upgrading to a real PLC controller and thus would greatly appreciate any help or tips with this issue...
Here is a snap of the setup (I know about the Wagos but I was tired of unscrewing the wires every time):

And this is the UI-section with temperature+ temperature- and power button as well as the display:

Safety hint: I am a certified IT-Systems electrician with permits for working with refrigerants. Don't kill yourself with mains voltage projects

Maybe some extras, fast diodes over relay coils, all unused pins to outputs, test it without anything connected to the relay switches, maybe you'll need Boucherot cells on relay switches. You can go for opto couplers or try SSR

I've added all of the ideas to the circuit. Some fast shotky diodes across the relay coils, 0.1µ + 150Ω snubbers over all AC relay switches as well as a 10µ cap and diode over the DC relay as well as setting all unused pins to OUTPUT and LOW.
It hasn't helped the issue much though. The Arduino still randomly crashes with the display attached but runs fine without. Oddly enough it doesn't need a relay switching to crash it, it just happens inbetween.
I really appreciate the help though!

SSRs or optocouplers would be something for a rebuild of the board with tons of isolation as there is no room on the current design. I'm still contemplating though wether to accept the boards will to be run without UI or to actually bite the bullet and start over from scratch.

If it happens even without relays it might be some memory issue, overusing Strings or something. You can try much stronger pull-up on reset line. And check 5V line with scope or something (also there is reset reason register in AVRs, you can try to check that). That's all I can think of other than redoing board

ESD protection is for protecting from high power surge caused by irregular power surge or lightning, it does not filter any noise coming into the circuit. What if you disconnect 5m long cable for temperature sensors (or only connect two temperature sensors locally without cable), but connect the display unit, will it still hang? 5m temp sensor ziptied to the main power wire is not a good idea.

i tend to think 10cm (although it looks to me it is more than 30cm long)  I2C should be okay unless there are some software bug that caused memory leak. To further isolate the problem, add decoupling capacitors 1uF and 0.1uF in parallel to each of the 5V rail, and connecting the display uint without the cable, will it help?

BTW, all the relays should have diode connect across its coil to prevent inrush current.

Alrighty. I've checked the memory usage with the MemoryUsage Library and it doesn't seem to cross the 1500-byte mark at any point in the operation - With display or without. Additionally, the sketch is very light. It contains the display library, a temp-conversion for the thermistors as well as a few if's to turn the relays on and off. There are only few variables used.

I've removed the remote temp sensors from the circuit and replaced them with a 10k resistor each directly at the board. It still runs fine without the display section but crashes after a few seconds if the display section is attached.
The display-line decoupling caps didn't work for me as the display refused to work after adding them, sadly, the Arduino also still crashed after several seconds.
The supply rails seem to be stable at 4.89V with a max 52mV ripple at the arduino when the compressor starts or shuts down.

@hcheung The ULN2003 chip has internal diodes meant to achieve exactly that. However after KIIV's suggestion I've also added aditional shotky diodes over every relay coil

The 5v line which powers the Nano is also switched via a relay back to the VFD so I guess it is more than a few mA. I would begin to suspect that. You've marked two pins as +5v but I guess this is actually the same pin. If, however, you are using Vin then that needs around 7 volts depending on the on board regulator. You can't use decoupling caps on the I2C bus. Is that what you meant in your  comment above when you said it failed?
I'd also suspect the code even though you have said it can be stable depending on what is switched on and how it is powered. Can you show this code?

The backfeed of the 5v to the VFD draws around 105mA to drive the VFD's logic. The way the manufacturer handled the external start/stop is apparently by interupting the power to the VFD's microcontroller. And yeah, the Arduino only has one 5V pin which both sides connect to. It was just simpler to draw the shematic parted in two sides for inputs & outputs. I know that the I2C bus shouldn't be decoupled as the data transmission is technically AC coupled to ground trough caps but I figured it was worth a try given the Arduino can source and sink a few mA trough it's pins.

So... I've finally figured it out. After spending nearly two days trying to debug this weird case, it turns out that my Arduino was apparently broken.
For a short while I switched the Nano with an ESP8266 with PCA9685 output expansion and level shifters to try and figure out if the USB cable I had attached during programming was giving me false readings when using the Serial port to debug. With that ESP8266 it worked flawlessly.
I then got curious about what other boards it would work with and tried out an Arduino Leonardo (Atmega 32u4) and later a 3rd party Uno which worked too.
I was quite weirded out to see that it worked with what was basically just a Nano on a larger board. Suspecting foul play by my old Nano, I ordered a replacement one which arrived today.
With the same program and wiring it works flawlessly, running hours on end without crashing.
So either I had a broken controller all along or the new one I got is a lucky chip that can deal with interference better than the old one.
I now have an Arduino nano labeled with "Don't use I2C" in the parts bin
I thank everyone wholeheartedly here for their help!
